# Assembly version ".001" becomes ".1"

Tags: c#, .net, assemblyversionattribute

In WinForms I have an AssemblVersion

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("01.01.01.002")]
```

However when the splash screen comes up it completely ignores the zeros showing:

```
1.1.1.2
```

as the version which is very inconvenient since later I will actually want to have an assembly version

```
 [assembly: AssemblyVersion("01.01.01.200")]
```

Is there a way to avoid this or do I Have to add some number at the beginning of last part of the version like so:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("01.01.01.102")]
```

Comment: The parts of the assembly version are converted to integers at some point (and then presumably back to a string): it's not possible to have leading zeros in the AssemblyVersion. *But*, it should be possible to add a different attribute with your exact string ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `AssemblyVersion` attribute stores it's information as a [`Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) object. The components of the `Version` struct are integers, and are treated as such. So `1.2.3.4 == 1.02.003.004` but `1.2.3.4 != 1.2.3.400`

You can use the [`AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyinformationalversionattribute.aspx) to provide aditional, arbitrarily formatted information about your product, as it's information is stored as a `string`, rather than a `Version`. So you can do:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.1.102")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("v.01 alpha")]
```

Or whatever you like

Comment: doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute?source=recommendations&view=net-7.0