# Product Version and File version of .net assemblies are not same after compilation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, .net-assembly

I am setting assembly and file version of .net assembly as below,

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("9.05.115.0")]

[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("9.05.115.0")]
```

After installing build, I was viewing the file details of the deployed files. I found that the Product Version is displayed correctly 9.05.115.0.

However, the File Version is displayed as 9.5.115.0. So why there no leading zero for “05” in the file version.

Is there any reason? Or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701632/is-it-appropriate-to-use-leading-zero-in-c-sharp-assembly-version):

> The versions are stored internally as integers, so even if you append
>   0 to the start of the version number, it will be converted to an int
>   and removed.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694568/assembly-version-001-becomes-1):

> The AssemblyVersion attribute stores it's information as a Version
>   object. The components of the Version struct are integers, and are
>   treated as such. So 1.2.3.4 == 1.02.003.004 but 1.2.3.4 != 1.2.3.400
>
> You can use the AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute to provide
>   aditional, arbitrarily formatted information about your product, as
>   it's information is stored as a string, rather than a Version. So you
>   can do:
>
> ```
> [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.1.102")] [assembly:
> AssemblyInformationalVersion("v.01 alpha")]
> ```
>
> Or whatever you like